# Why PowerShell 5 still looking for old PowerShell Gallery path after it was renamed?

Tags: powershell

I have a local PowerShell Gallery that I renamed to JnPSGallery.
I unregistered the old path `\\\Ryzen\G$\JnPowerShellGallery` and then registered the new path `\\\Ryzen\G$\JnPSGallery`, but PowerShell 5 is still trying to look for the old path when I use the  Update-Module command. I even tried unregistering all repositories and then typed in Update-Module to see what would happen.

I get the error 'PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to find repository `\\\Ryzen\G$\JnPowerShellGallery`. Use `Get-PSRepository` to see all available repositories.' Even with all repositories unregistered, it is still looking for the old PowerShell Gallery path.

Update-Module after registering new JnPSGallery path.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHxuw.png

Update-Module after removing all registered repositories.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4qxF.png

How do I stop PowerShell 5 from trying to use the old path `\\\Ryzen\G$\JnPowerShellGallery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Joel & adrian.anderson. I fixed my problem!

Joel on http://slack.poshcode.org/ powershell-help channel suggested that some of my installed modules might still be referencing my old PSGallery path. He was right!

When I woke up this morning, I  opened PowerShell 5, typed in Get-InstalledModule and there right in front of me were the two modules that were still referencing my old PSGallery path.  I uninstalled those modules and the errors went away.

I had originally thought the problem was with the PowerShellGet module. I feel silly now.

Get-InstalledModule showing two modules referencing old gallery.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBcOY.png

Thanks to Joel it saved me from re-installing Windows.